# iOS memory debugging

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiscrollview, memory-management

I have a lazy loading `UIScroll` view which keeps three active pages: `n-1`, `n` and `n+1` and deallocates views outside of the 3-page range. I do see that `dealloc` is being called for unnecessary views and yet when I monitor the memory allocation in `Instruments` while scrolling I see that Live Bytes increase by 5K each time I scroll the `UIScrollView`. The number of Living object also keeps increasing despite keeping only 3 active views in the `UIScrollView`.

The app does not crash or issue memory warning, however, I'm trying to figure out if this is a memory leak I should be aware of. Analyzing the code does not issue any memory leaks warnings.

Any thoughts? Does that mean that memory is leaking along the way?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code that loads new pages and remove old. Let's see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

run instruments using heapshot analysis. it will tell you the allocations and object changes over a period of execution.

Comment: Justin, I ran the heap shot analysis and I don't see the heap growing or the number of object allocation increasing. Does that mean it's all tip-top ?

Comment: @user628896 Did you change your implementation since posting your question? *while scrolling I see that Live Bytes increase by 5K each time I scroll the UIScrollView. The number of Living object also keeps increasing despite keeping only 3 active views in the UIScrollView.* does not agree with *I don't see the heap growing or the number of object allocation increasing*. To analyze: Record. Navigate to the page and load 3 pages. Mark the Heap. Scroll and load more pages to get the growth you originally wrote about. Mark the Heap again. End recording.